# AWS DMS migration not migrated Foreign keys, sequences and indexes got renamed

Tags: aws, amazon-rds-aurora, amazon-dms

I have used DMS for AURORA PostgreSQL to PostgreSQL SCHEMA Migration. Migrate Data only type is used for DMS activity.

After a Full load of Data, all tables were created on the target endpoint with all data along with it.

The problem is when we cross-checked with target DB, It hasn't had Foreign Keys, Sequences in target, and Some Indexes got renamed. Also, DDL doesnt have the default statements, and Defaults in tables are blank.
Does DMS not take of these?

Comment: I have the same issue , the fix will be here https://youtu.be/kJs9U4ys5FE?t=1702 use SCT to apply schema drop constraint after DMS restore them back

Comment: here is the answer for foreign keys https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96961/how-to-temporarily-disable-foreign-keys-in-amazon-rds-postgresql